# Same Permalink for Different WordPress Objects with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Is it possible to use the same permalink structure for different types of WordPress objects, such as posts, pages, or custom post types, using the add_rewrite_rule function? How can this be effectively implemented, and what are the implications and best practices to consider?

I've been researching extensively on how to achieve this functionality, but I'm still grappling with some aspects. I'd appreciate any insights, experiences, or pointers to reliable resources that could help me navigate this topic effectively.